# Do the official USAV rules for mixed volleyball require all rotations to be same gender?

Tags: rules, volleyball

I am playing in a mixed league, and they state that if a team has more than 6 people, they can use a rotation substitution, but that

> A player must substitute for the same gender (i.e. men sub for men / women sub for women).

And they claim that it is based on USAV rules... but is this anywhere in the USAV rules? I have checked as thoroughly as I can and the closest I've found is that if a Libero is used,

> a female Libero may only replace regular female players. A male Libero may only replace regular male players.
>    But that does not apply to our league as we do not use Liberos.

This rule sucks for our team of 7 players, as we are forced to choose one gender to rotate out while the other gender plays the whole time, rather than everybody rotating evenly. I have looked at rules for other mixed leagues and haven't seen anything like it.

Comment: Hi Nij, good point, but the league managers claim that their rotation rules are based on the USAV rules, which is why I am asking. I edited my original post to reflect that.

Comment: *"Based on"* is often code for *"we started there and changed a few things that we didn't like"*. But any answer will make clear whether that has happened, now.